# Bootstrap fileinput

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Krajee's Bootstrap Fileinput (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) and having some problems getting it to work with .Net MVC.

I'm doing a normal form submit (I need to do this because there is a lot of processing on the client side)

This is a cut down version of the code:

My model is:

```
public class AddFormModel
{
    public string txtName { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] fileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Index.Html:

```
@model TestSystem.Models.AddFormModel
@{
     Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.5/themes/fa/theme.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmMain" action="@Url.Action("AddObject", "Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName, null, new { @required = "", @class = "form-control", data_val = "false" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="file-loading">
                    <input id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" class="file" type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="1" data-upload-url="#">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

<script>
$("#fileUpload").fileinput({
    theme: 'fa',
    showUpload: false,
    showClose: false,
    showRemove: false,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pdf'],
    overwriteInitial: false,
    minFileCount: 0,
    maxFileCount: 5,
    maxFileSize: 4000,
    validateInitialCount: true,
    slugCallback: function (filename) {
        return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
    },
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    fileActionSettings: {
        showRemove: true,
        showUpload: false,
        showZoom: false,
        showDrag: false,
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddObject(AddFormModel model)
    {
         // ****When I look at the model here I only see 1 file ****
         //     model.txtName <- this is ok
         //     model.fileUpload <- If I just put one file in the upload
         //                         I can see it
         //     model.fileUpload <- If I put more than one file in the upload
         //                         I can only see the last one
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I meant to put:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
around the Controller method - my mistake when posting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload more than one file, you need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which you already have in form tag.

And Model list of `HttpPostedFileBase` to catch multiple files you have sent

```
public class AddFormModel
{
    public string txtName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

All other parts seems fine to me.

**UPDATE**

I have tried your code it's working fine at my side when i posted form with more than one file all file has been retrieved in controller's method `model.fileUpload.Count();`

One more thing to notice `[HttpPost]` is on wrong place it should on the method rather than on controller class

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase[]` is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Comment: Ohh sorry i missed `[]` :(

Comment: Hi, I tried adding:
    
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload { get; set; }

Still getting just last file in model.fileUpload and model.fileUpload.Count() is still 1

Comment: @Wattcey ohh that's not an issue i just missed `[]` this you code seems good to me and i have tried the same code and it's working so fine there are multiple files fetched in controller's `POST` method